# Abstain, Maintain : Abstinence, Maintenance spelling difference between verb and noun

Tags: orthography

Regarding the verbs Abstain and Maintain, why are they spelt differently as nouns Abstinence, Maintenance even though they seem like they would have similar spelling.

Comment: Because English spelling and pronunciation [just don't make no cents](http://www.spellingsociety.org/news/media/poems.php) (or scents, or sense).

Comment: Also for the earlier vowel in "maint**e**nance," see this question: [Why is it spelled “maintenance” and not “maintainance?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227497)