# Why is it spelled "maintenance" and not "maintainance?"

Tags: orthography, writing

Why is the task of maintaining spelled "maintenance" and not "maintainance?"

Other words related to maintaining include: maintain, maintained, maintainer, maintainability, and maintainable. Each of those words starts with ***maintai-***, so it would logically make sense to write **maintainance** instead of **maintenance** because it would have the same "ai" instead of "e".

Comment: It's English.  Nothing more needs be said (except to get to the minimum character count).

Comment: The word *maintenance* comes from Old French, where it was (sometimes) spelled the same way. But the vowel in the second syllable of *maintain* changed. So the spelling of *maintain* got changed to reflect the pronunciation. Since the pronunciation of *maintenance* was consistent with the spelling, the French spelling was kept.

Comment: A related question might be, Why isn't it spelled _maintinence_, on the model of _contain/continence_ and _pertain/pertinence_?

Comment: @SvenYargs: That one at least has a clear, if useless, explanation: because of Latin (continere, pertinere, but "maintain" developed in French from Latin "manu tenere")

Comment: @sumelic: Good comment here, and good answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Oh phooey! This means I have to Memorize?
Would you show the examples of the words in question with the diphthong in place as it immigrated from France?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to (2) put comments / follow-on questions as 'comments', and (1) build up enough rep points to do so.

Comment: It doth boil the blood

Answer (score 21):

There is no rule that related segments of words have to be spelled with the same sequence of letters. It might seem more logical to you, but that's never been a successful argument in changing English spelling*. We also write "deception", "deceive" and "deceit", and "reception","receive", and "receipt".

In any case, the second digraph "ai" in "maintain" is not even etymological, but secondary: according to the OED, the French source word was spelled variously as "meintenir," "maintenir" and "maynteigner." The OED entry on "maintain" further states:

> The English forms probably partly reflect stem variation in Old
>   French, where stress on the stem in parts of the paradigm gives e.g.
>   3rd singular present indicative *-tient*, 3rd singular present
>   subjunctive *-tiegne, -teigne* (although with much mixture of forms
>   through analogy; Middle English forms suggesting pronunciations with
>   close *ē* and with *ī* probably reflect respectively Anglo-Norman and
>   northern Old French developments of *-ie-* )

So the verb "maintain" either had or developed a diphthong in the stressed second syllable when it was imported into English, but the use of the specific digraph "ai" to spell this sound was arbitrary: it could just as well have been spelled "maintein", or even "maintean" with the sound of the "ea" in "great". In Middle English or Early Modern English, before our spelling became standardized, you might encounter spellings like "mainteyne" and "deceave". The standardized spellings these words ended up with are fairly arbitrary.

The second syllable of 'maintenance" is unstressed and does not have a diphthong, so it didn't need to be respelled with "ai." Despite this, though, forms like "maintaynence," "maneteinance," "manteanance" and and even "manteignance" were sometimes used in the past according to the OED, but they did not win out in the end. I don't know if these spelling variants correspond to variant pronunciations, or if they were just affected by the spelling of the related verb as with the modern non-standard variant "maintainance."

The word "maintained" is not just related; it's actually the past tense form of the verb "maintain", so it's to be expected that we use the same spelling. "Maintain" is a regular verb in English. The words "maintainer," "maintainable," and "maintainability" all relate to the verb via common suffixes that generally take the verb as the stem without altering it (we can compare "explain," "explanation," and "explainable").

*With the marginal exception of Noah Webster, but even he didn't get all that he wanted

Comment: Related: [Why drop the “i” in “explanation”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78272/why-drop-the-i-in-explanation)

Comment: @sumerlic: or why drop the *u* in *pronunciation*

Answer (score 4):

This can be explained by looking at where these words come from: French.

In French, *to maintain* is *maintenir*, literally: *to handhold*.  The stress is, as expected, on the last syllable.

So what is *I maintain* in French?  It is *je maintiens*, literally: *I handhold*.  Forget about that closing *-s*, it is silent.  What matters is that, once again, the stress is on the last syllable, and that in French, we can't have a stressed syllable *ten* or *tens*: it has long become *tien* or *tiens* by a pronunciation change called [palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages#Palatalization).

Finally, what is *maintenance*?  Simple: *maintenance*.  Once again, the stress is on the last syllable, so the *-e-* in the middle was never palatalized.  While *je maintens* is impossible because the *-e-* isn't palatalized, the word *maintienance* is equally impossible: if the syllable *is* palatalized, it *must* carry stress, which it doesn't here.

And now, these words were borrowed by English:

1. *Je maintiens* became *I maintain*.
2. Unlike in French, English infinitives are simply the verb stems, so *to maintain* became the infinitive.
3. *Maintenance* was also borrowed, and it stayed the way it was.

Comment: I was taught that French has equal stress in all words.

Comment: @Dog Lover: it doesn't. [Stress is on the last full syllable.](https://www.google.nl/search?hl=en&q=french+stress&tbs=li:1&gws_rd=cr&ei=wj5jWdmiJ8rawQLC7KWwCg)